# Displaying simple array in database query

Tags: php, mysql

I was using the following to display a table listing the official symbols of the fifty states:

```
echo <<<EOD
   <tr>
     <td><a href="/world/$PlaceL" title="$Place">$Place</a></td>
     <td>$Symbol</td>
   </tr>
EOD;
```

However, I need to modify it to display state songs, as some states have several official songs. So in my while loop, I changed this...

```
$Symbol = $row['Symbol'];
```

to this...

```
$Song[] = $row['Symbol'];
```

However, I don't know what to do next. This doesn't work...

```
echo <<<EOD
   <tr>
     <td><a href="/world/$PlaceL" title="$Place">$Place</a></td>
     <td>echo join( $Song, '' );</td>
   </tr>
EOD;
```

This is better...

```
$Song[] = '<td>'.$Symbol.'</td>';

echo <<<EOD
   <tr>
     <td><a href="/world/$PlaceL" title="$Place">$Place</a></td>
     echo join( $Song, '' );
   </tr>
EOD;
```

But it displays all the songs in a single row (among other problems). I would like to display multiple rows, like this:

Tennessee | My Tennessee | official song

Tennessee | Rocky Top | official folk song

Can anyone tell me how to modify my code to display the rows properly? Thx.

EDIT:

This is my query...

```
SELECT GS.N, GS.IDArea SymArea, GS.URL, GS.IDSymbol,
 GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GS.DesigGen, GS.Date, GG.N, GG.IDArea, GG.URL GURL, GG.Name GName,   GG.Type, GG.IDParent, GG.IDParent2, GG.Parent, GG.ParentName, GG.Parent2, GG.IDReg
FROM gs AS GS
LEFT JOIN gw_geog AS GG ON GG.IDArea = GS.IDArea
WHERE GS.DesigGen = 'song' AND GG.IDParent = 'usa'
GROUP BY GS.IDSymbol ORDER BY GS.N
```

And here are a couple rows from the primary database table, GS...

```
GS.N | IDArea | IDSymbol | URL | Symbol | DesigGen | Date
4431 | us-tn | us-tn-Songs | tennessee/songs | The Pride of Tennessee | song | 1996
4432 | us-tn | us-tn-Song2 | tennessee/songs | My Tennessee | song | 1996
```

The table gw_geog simply contains data on geographic locations (e.g. the fifty states). For example, GG.URL = south-dakota, GG.Name = South Dakota, and GG.Parent = usa.

Comment: You'll need to show us your database scheme and the code (including SQL) you're using to retrieve the data. As it stands, I have no clue what your data looks like before you start `echo`ing it.

Comment: OK, I edited my initial post, including the query ad some data from the database table.

Comment: It may be simpler to abandon the heredoc syntax in this example so you can do easier formatting of songs by using a `foreach($Song as $s) { //... }` code block.